# Glibc Compilation Error

Tags: linux, compilation, compiler-errors, makefile, glibc

I'm compiling glibc-2.12.1 in Ubuntu 10.10 (32 bit in VirtualBox).
Steps followed:

1. configure --prefix=/usr --disable-asm
2. make

[I'm building it from a new directory]

I'm getting the following errors on running make:

```
gcc ../sysdeps/i386/fpu/s_frexp.S -c -D__NO_MATH_INLINES -D__LIBC_INTERNAL_MATH_INLINES -I../include -I/home/l33thckr/Installations/glibc-build/math -I/home/l33thckr/Installations/glibc-build -I../sysdeps/i386/elf -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686 -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686 -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386 -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386 -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../nptl/sysdeps/pthread -I../sysdeps/pthread -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux -I../sysdeps/gnu -I../sysdeps/unix/common -I../sysdeps/unix/mman -I../sysdeps/unix/inet -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/i386 -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv -I../sysdeps/unix/i386 -I../nptl/sysdeps/unix -I../sysdeps/unix -I../sysdeps/posix -I../sysdeps/i386/i686/fpu -I../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch -I../nptl/sysdeps/i386/i686 -I../sysdeps/i386/i686 -I../sysdeps/i386/i486 -I../nptl/sysdeps/i386/i486 -I../sysdeps/i386/fpu -I../nptl/sysdeps/i386 -I../sysdeps/i386 -I../sysdeps/wordsize-32 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64 -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32 -I../sysdeps/ieee754 -I../sysdeps/generic/elf -I../sysdeps/generic -I../nptl  -I.. -I../libio -I.  -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include ../include/libc-symbols.h  -DPIC -DSHARED     -DASSEMBLER  -DGAS_SYNTAX  -Wa,--noexecstack  -Wa,-mtune=i686 -o /home/l33thckr/Installations/glibc-build/math/s_frexp.os -MD -MP -MF /home/l33thckr/Installations/glibc-build/math/s_frexp.os.dt -MT /home/l33thckr/Installations/glibc-build/math/s_frexp.os 
../sysdeps/i386/fpu/s_frexp.S: 
Assembler messages:
../sysdeps/i386/fpu/s_frexp.S:66: Error: invalid identifier for ".ifdef"
../sysdeps/i386/fpu/s_frexp.S:66: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `1'
../sysdeps/i386/fpu/s_frexp.S:66: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `1'
../sysdeps/i386/fpu/s_frexp.S:66: Error: Missing symbol name in directive
../sysdeps/i386/fpu/s_frexp.S:66: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `1'
../sysdeps/i386/fpu/s_frexp.S:66: Error: Missing symbol name in directive
../sysdeps/i386/fpu/s_frexp.S:66: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `.'
../sysdeps/i386/fpu/s_frexp.S:66: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `1'
../sysdeps/i386/fpu/s_frexp.S:66: Error: expected comma after name `' in .size directive
../sysdeps/i386/fpu/s_frexp.S:66: Error: ".endif" without ".if"
../sysdeps/i386/fpu/s_frexp.S:66: Error: junk `.get_pc_thunk.dx' after expression
make[2]: *** [/home/l33thckr/Installations/glibc-build/math/s_frexp.os] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/l33thckr/Installations/glibc-2.12.1/math'
make[1]: *** [math/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/l33thckr/Installations/glibc-2.12.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried using --disable-asm (in configure --prefix=/usr --disable-asm) but it still gives the same error.

Searching on Google revealed that this problem has been present for a long time [ Reference: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.glibc.user/758 ].

What is causing this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by your GCC defining `__i686`. You can confirm that in fact it does that with this command:

```
gcc -dD -E -xc /dev/null | grep __i686
```

If this command produces output, then that's the problem. To fix it, use:

```
configure --prefix=/usr CC='gcc -U__i686'
```

or build a newer version of glibc.

========================================================================
EDIT:

Some other links which were useful:

[Awk Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396923/error-while-using-make-to-compile-glibc-2-11-1-for-linux-from-scratch)

[Gawk Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244268/installing-gawk-4-0-on-ubuntu-12-04)

[Update software on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95336/why-cant-i-update-applications-without-upgrading-the-whole-os)